# Not able to run oozie workflow with java action

Tags: java, hadoop, oozie, hue

I am submitting a oozie workflow, I designed in Hue and it contains a few  java actions.

Hue submits and attempts to execute the oozie workflow, I always get the following error.

```
 Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain], main() threw exception, begin > end in range (begin, end)
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: begin > end in range (begin, end): (1399708804155, 1399694415805)
```

I have no clue as to what it means and what I am supposed to do about it. From the error message, I am able to infer that the submission time of the workflow happens later than the 
completion time.

But I don't know what is causing this and what I need to do to fix this.

Any inputs on this will be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you've got some clock skew between some of the hosts in your hadoop cluster. I'm guessing the oozie server and whichever host ran the launcher for your job. Those values look like timestamps in milliseconds since the epoch. And it would make sense for it to be an error if the `begin` timestamp was greater than the `end` timestamp.

Comment: that was what it was.

Comment: For those who reached till this answer and said 'oh yeah! I am gonna fix this', run  `sudo ntpdate-debian` if you are on debian/ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

As we know Illegal Argument exception usually thrown when a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate arguments.

I can see the range you passed to some of your method begin and end 1399708804155, 1399694415805. The end range is lower than begin range. If your java is designed as such or try to look in this arguments. All the best !!

Answer (score 0):

Is the Java workflow example that comes with Hue working for you? Is workflow with a single Java action working? (it could be a setup problem)

You can send more detailed info to [hue-list](http://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/group/hue-user).